# Allocation of memory ( C++ ) Compile-time/Run-time?

Tags: c++, memory, compiler-construction, constructor, compilation

I am not sure how appropriate is this question, but -

*I am curious about how the compiler sets memory aside for an object (allocation of memory) even before it is constructed (before even the constructor is called!)*.

*How does it happen for primitive datatypes?*

This sounds a bit naive, but what exactly is it ?

Is it entirely a run time process, or does it (the compiler) have any plans like *to do this*, *to do that*, during run-time, which it decides before hand during the *compile- time*. I have no idea at all!

> An object, be it a primitive type, a pointer, or a instance of a big class, occupies a certain known amount of memory. That memory must somehow be set aside for the object. In some circumstances, that set-aside memory is initialized. That initialization is what constructors do. They do not set aside (or allocate) the memory needed to store the object. That step is performed before the constructor is called.

In other words, when does the memory allocation for literally ANY kind of variable happen, in terms of time, at which point? At which step in compilation (or run-time)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory allocation always happens at run time.  Memory reservation, for objects that reside on the stack, or for static variables, happens at compile time (or at run time for C99 VLAs).

Memory for an object's members is always in place before the constructor runs. It is the job of the compiler and its runtime support to ensure that is so.

Comment: Static variables may be given space in the executable file itself (which is then memory-mapped into the process' address space), so they're quite literally allocated at compile-time. :)

Comment: Thanks david ... :) But this leads to a small issue . **Memory allocation** and **Memory reservation** ! From what you said , I understand that there is a difference between the two . Can you explain it to me ? :)

Comment: @jalf I've forgotten about that. I've added static variables to the category that I refer to as reserved rather than allocation.

Comment: Think about variables on the stack, consider an int for sake of argument. The compiler decides at compile time the location of the int, relative to the function's stack frame. The memory is actually allocated by the system before the function is called, but the compiler has reserved some of it, at a known location, relative to the function's stack frame. So I'd say the difference is that the location (at least relative to stack frame) is known at compile time. For a heap allocated int, the location is only determined at runtime when the allocation executes.

Comment: Thanks david :) ...  But I want to know it in detail .. Can you suggest me some link or what do i google for precise information regarding the topic ?                                                  PS : I tried phrases like " Compiler memory issues " etcetera , but were not of much use !!

Comment: Ask detailed questions here. But ask very specific ones. This question is quite broad (nothing wrong with that). Ask how the memory is allocated for an int, for all the possible storage classes. And so on.

Comment: @Appy: David's, Dave's, and Marc's answer are all good; David is reserving the word "allocation" for dynamically allocated memory. Whether memory is dynamically allocated, reserved on the stack, or reserved in the program itself, the amount of memory that must be set aside is known at compile time in C++. C++ is a statically-typed language.

Comment: Nice answer. I think this is also why, in C++, we need .h files. Header files seems liek the only way for the compiler to calculate allocation size in case of stack allocation (i.e.: a method call with a non-pointer reference/object parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Allocation objects created with `new` or `new[]` or some variant is done at runtime, by accessing the freestore and finding enough space to place the new object, prior to the constructor running.

Allocation for local objects within a function are done at runtime.  However, this is usually accomplished by moving a stack pointer the correct size of bytes, and the space between the previous value and the new value is now reserved for the object.  The constructors are run after the space is run.

Allocation for global and static objects are done at compile time by the compiler, and their constructors are run when the translation unit they are defined in is loaded (usually before main() begins executing).

Allocation for objects contained directly (not via pointer) within another object is done as part of the allocation for that object.

Comment: I'd say that allocation for local objects for the most part is done at compile time, since the compiler emits machine code that expects the objects to be at a particular offset relative to the current stack frame, and this offset is decided at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

There's (loosely speaking) three typical scenarios: allocation on the stack, allocation from heap, and static allocation.

The first is what happens whenever you declare a local variable within a function:

```
void foo ( )
{
   int bar = 42;
}
```

Here, the memory for `bar` is allocated on the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). It is allocated at the time `foo` is called.

The second scenario happens when you create a class instance with the `new` operator:

```
void foo ( )
{
    MyClass* bar = new MyClass( );
}
```

Here, the memory for `i` is allocated on the [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_memory). This again happens at runtime, and occurs as the `new` operator executes. It works essentially in the same manner a C's `malloc`, if you're more familiar with that.

Finally, there's static allocation.

```
void foo ( )
{
    static int bar = 42;
}
```

Here, the compiler knows ahead of time that memory will be needed for `bar`, and so it inserts into the executable an instruction telling the executable loader to reserve space, or literally makes a space in the executable for the variable to reside in. The memory for `bar` is therefore typically still allocated at runtime, as the executable loads.

Comment: I doubt that static allocation "literally" takes up space in the executable image. Imagine a global `char buf[1000000];` Your executable won't grow by 1MB, but rather, the memory is set aside at *load time*.

Answer (score 0):

A more fundamental answer to this question is that every process has two basic types of memory that it deals with. "Instructions" and "Data".  When the compiler is generating a program it splits the data and instructions, and allocates these two types of memory into different pieces of the program. The pieces are broken down into page sized chunks usually.

At run time the loader reads the sizes of these memory areas from the program and allocates virtual memory on the processes behalf. It doesn't necessarily load all the instructions or data at that time. A program can be much bigger then the available physical memory on a machine.

So when a program says `static float foo;` The compiler allocates at least sizeof(float) bytes of memory which becomes an actual part of the program. The same can be said for global variables. On large programs the program's data can easily become many megabytes in size.

Be careful not to confuse this with stack memory. Which is allocated and initialized at program startup but has nothing to do with program data.

The program data is fixed in size at startup. But this doesn't mean "constant" the program data can change. I famous trick many programmers use (sometimes as a hack, sometimes for debugging, rarely for a well written piece of software) is to create a static variable inside a function for example:

```
static int debug=0;
if( debug ) {
     cout << "we have a debug point\n"; 
     debug = 0;
 }
... (some code later)
debug = 1;
```

The keyword "static" is telling the compiler to store this variable in the program data. The code itself will not print out "we have a debug point" until debug becomes true. This can be used to prevent debug output spew, trap out an unexpected result ect. Because this data is part of the program data it doesn't go out of scope ever so we can rely on it holding the same value every time the function the code snippet is in gets called.

It is also very common to see pointers used as global and or static variables for at least some data. This used to be popular with singletons. The pointer is  permanently allocated but can point to anything we want.

When a program requests more memory at run time through an interface like "new" that memory comes from the same basic pool of memory as the static program data but it is considered dynamic since it is being requested at runtime. Here again, dynamic memory gets virtual addresses but won't actually get physically backed addresses until it is used. So again a program can allocate massive amounts of dynamic memory without actually having that physical memory. (at least on operating systems that are worth their salt...some operating systems are poorly designed and won't allow this)

Finally, there is the stack. The stack is created by the loader and becomes part of the process.  It is called a stack because it literally allocates memory just like a stack data structure. The vast majority of temporary variables get allocated on the stack. It is completely separate from the program data, and dynamically allocated "heap" memory but still comes from the same fundamental pool of memory as everything else. Again the stack is allocated in page sized chunks. On Unix and Linux the program stack can grow unbounded. Windows isn't as generous.

For example:

```
int cube( int a )
{
   int cubed = a*a*a;
   return cubed;
}
```

In this we have 3 variables. The value being passed into cube, the temporary and the return value. It should come as no surprise that all these values will end up on the stack. The stack can be though of as having values pushed and popped. In this case the sequence would be to push the input "a" then push the variable "cubed" then do the return. Return is slightly different in that we pop everything that the function pushed and then push the result. The point here isn't to understand how a stack is managed, but to recognize that all the data here lives on the stack.

Most every program boils down to these fundamental rules. Some systems play games of not having a stack. Some systems don't have a heap. But if you apply the "what memory did this come from" question to any variable, or allocation then you can easily figure out its expected behavior.